# View is not displaying returned data from controller in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am sending data through HttpClient (Json) from console app to web app, everything is working well but the only issue Iam facing that data sent from controller to view is not displayed. I debugged the program and i can see that data are returned to the view. Following are the codes:

Constroller:

```
using ( var db = new MessageDBContext())
{
    try
    {
        db.Messages.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Saving Messages into db Error 1: " + e.EntityValidationErrors);
    }
}
return View(model);
```

Controller Debugg:

[image: Debugg controller]

and here is the view code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Display(@Model.message)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Display(@Model.time)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

View Debugg:

[image: View Debugg]

So why the data are not displayed to the html view!?

Comment: Why do you need to use the `Html.Display` helper, why not simply write out the result `<td>@Model.message</td>`

Comment: @Kane its not working i tried it :(

Comment: Have you tried DisplayFor?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk it wont work, i did

Comment: @moji try to see in browser's inspector, it maybe css error

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.message)

Comment: @SurenSrapyan browsers inspector shows nothing,, it shows empty div

Comment: How about trying `Html.Raw` ?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk it wont work

Comment: @moji empty div? the table doesn't generates ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan no it does not

Comment: @moji try to delete the Razors statements from the code and try again.If it will not generate the table, try to see the table's classes.If not works try to add the Razor view explicitly

Comment: @MattMurdock doesnt work i tried it

Comment: @moji - Try removing that `@` symbol and write it like this : @Html.Display(Model.message). Dont know if that would work, but give it a try if you haven't.

Comment: Could you try to use DisplayFor one more time? Use this code @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.message)

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk nothing :( it wont display anything

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the model to the correct view? Your debugger shows the table has id="treatmentTable" but your view code doesn't.

Comment: Could you please make a tiny project for us which shows the same bechaviour and publish it somewhere (github, etc)

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk https://github.com/momo0002/Client-Server-App

Comment: Your model is always empty because the Index method (HttpPost) is never called. Where is this call?

Comment: By the way, DisplayFor works good

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk no bro, the post request is made by the console app using httpclient, it's suppose to write in the console and show data in the browser..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96788/discussion-between-sergii-zhevzhyk-and-moji).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of this case:

```
 @if (Model != null)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.message)
            </td>
            <td>
                @* Or *@
                @Model.time
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add some information to this question. The controller method which (shown in the question) is marked with HttpPost attribute and is called from the console application. Of course, the result is returned to the console and NOT to the browser. In the browser the controller returns empty model `return View();` Otherwise, the DisplayFor method would work perfectly. If you want to update the display in your browser you need to write more code to establish server->client communication.